# Data signing with Azure KeyVault and SHA1 hashing algorithm

Tags: c#, azure, sha1

I’m storing my private key in the Azure KeyVault using the command.

Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName `vault-name` -Name `myprivatekey` –KeyFilePath `cert.pfx` -KeyFilePassword $securepfxpwd

I have set up a KeyVault client application as it is described here: http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/authenticating-a-client-application-with-azure-key-vault/

Then I’m using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault (0.9.1 – prerelease version) package to access it from my C# code. I can get the key and sign data using the key. It works fine.

My problem is that I have to use SHA1 hashing algorithm when signing data. And it seems that it is currently not supported. This is the list of the hashing algorithms from the code constants: RS256, RS384 ,RS512, RSNULL.

Are there any options or workarounds in my case to perform signing using Azure KeyVault and SHA1 hashing algorithm?

Comment: Those *are* [SHA2 keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn903623.aspx#BKMK_RSA_HSMAlgorithms) - SHA256 to SHA512. SHA1 isn't considered safe any more

Comment: You can use `RSNULL` with any hash whose size is compatible with the key. However this algorithm will not specify the `digestAlgorithm` in the `DigestInfo` structure (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313). Hence the verifier must be ready to understand the signature. However if you can influence the verifier, the best thing to do is use `RS256` or other.

Comment: A newer version of this question has answers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079983/create-rsa-sha1-signature