# How to implement sha-1 with Microsoft Azure key vault with java?

Tags: bouncycastle, sha1, azure-keyvault, java-security

I need to implement in Java a sign with Key Vault using Sha1 algorithm, but is not supported, how can i implement, I've try to do de digest with bouncy castle and use key vault client with RSNULL algorithm, but the result is nos correct.

```
    String stringToSign = "holamund";
    byte[] digestSha1Bytes = DigestUtils.sha1(stringToSign.getBytes());
    keyOperationResult = keyVaultClient.sign("AZURE_URL_KEY",   JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.RSNULL, digestSha1Bytes);
```

output generated: IoGXIIIZ5ZyM2m7ozz/ET8UOWWTwmKeseJVvs9w9cPHz11wKFZ/ikGx2Sj4Adhcn32QCDBOSv/knaTvPyw+EXkVX/3NrAmxuIUUGhQF4/muu7Y2644IWuECXqp8o1iXL8mN7sCEB5sh0sNArK77dvfRk7A0unZR/82wpFxMjxYYeh8k/CiFRHK/MWX6sZe+1Rm6vDmkaodyRqR1LsusS0wzOiuVdTXNkyL55MaTs5cLpWIpbHU+H4YaAO1+B+nFVkJeeDDGbjHvmMO1EO/KT7HSHReOukYR2mwKxklzCZA3DWRp3pSi9Rdirpoc/IvFIOcWcYK44xfx0UKVHDzhZ4w==

output expected: pHOyaoTuOTELmTbfgRPg12tJP0JdjQY1GsdMR63s8L8hMb4lsirmalxSVRm5D2ed2d6PMdMxvA+OjUW/Pxzx5R8M5b3SeIiXde5JloOKoOc2PbKIGJI5Sf7+yCSowCSgTdxmwkTQdBCZWeRhw1hs5hNJW/uBkbImdF0RtR478JxePH9AYEHOFjanLlI5/OHzduPS8Px9qzQIr/KYRWk32Z14dUGPctYeT5ttY7lYu4ksTeyCwea5booNaZAN8EnT41s564cCPR2ZdYirzcNnWlTQxD7innpuFWP+rvLZHLYp3y+iiYIU6eyJurDoTUHHzTp+mEQSD/IMtgE43FWb6w==

I`ve tried to do digest with different api's like bouncy castle, java native, etc., but not fins correct convention to work with key vault sign.

Comment: Did you check the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730001/data-signing-with-azure-keyvault-and-sha1-hashing-algorithm?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079983/create-rsa-sha1-signature)?

Comment: Yes, i don't find a solution for java, some ones talk about Digest implementation in C#, but i´m working with java,and using same API, I,m evaluating to move to azure, but if i can not find solution for this it won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Key Vault, the `RSNULL` algorithm provides a raw `RSA` signature. In order to produce a standard `SHA1` signature with a raw `RSA` signature algorithm, you must first wrap your digest into an `ASN.1 DigestInfo` structure that will be signed. The following sample shows that:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.Signature;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyBundle;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyOperationResult;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.webkey.JsonWebKey;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.webkey.JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm;

...

/**
 * @param keyVaultClient An instance of Key Vault client.
 * @param keyIdentifer The Key Identifier. This is the kid field of JsonWebKey structure.
 * @param message The message to be signed.
 */
void sampleSHA1SignatureWithAzureKeyVault(KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient, String keyIdentifer, byte[] message) throws Throwable {

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    // Signs message using Azure Key Vault //
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    // Compute SHA1 hash:
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    md.update(message);
    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    // Convert SHA1 digest into ASN.1:
    byte[] digestInfo = getDigestInfoForSHA1Digest(digest);

    // Call Azure Key Vault to perform the signature using the server key.
    // Note that we are passing the DigestInfo to RSNULL, instead of SHA1 digest.
    KeyOperationResult result = keyVaultClient.sign(keyIdentifer, JsonWebKeySignatureAlgorithm.RSNULL, digestInfo);
    byte[] signature = result.result();

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Verifies the signature locally, using java.security //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Read the public key from Azure Key Vault
    KeyBundle keyBundle = keyVaultClient.getKey(keyIdentifer);

    // Initialize java.security instances with the Public Key and message.
    KeyPair kp = keyBundle.key().toRSA(false);
    Signature signImpl = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signImpl.initVerify(kp.getPublic());
    signImpl.update(message);

    // Verify the signature.
    if (signImpl.verify(signature))
        System.out.println("Signature was verified.");
    else
        System.out.println("Signature verification failed.");
}

byte[] getDigestInfoForSHA1Digest(byte[] digest) {

    // Constructs an ASN.1 DigestInfo structure for the caller-specified SHA1 hash.

    // ASN.1 data:
    byte[] digestInfo = new byte[] { //
            0x30, 0x21, // SEQUENCE DigestInfo (33 bytes) (13 of header + 20 of SHA1 digest)
            0x30, 0x09, // SEQUENCE AlgorithmIdentifier (9 bytes)
            0x06, 0x05, // OBJECT IDENTIFIER algorithm (5 bytes)
            0x2b, 0x0e, 0x03, 0x02, 0x1a, // OID of SHA1 (1.3.14.3.2.26)
            0x05, 0x00, // NUL algorithm parameters (05 00 is the DER encoding for NUL)
            0x04, 0x14, // OCTET STRING digest (20 bytes)
            00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00 // SHA1, copied below
    };

    System.arraycopy(digest, 0, digestInfo, 15, digest.length);

    return digestInfo;
}
```